# Encoding Decoding Python

Tags: python, encoding, decoding

I have text "**confrères**" in a text file with encoded format "ISO-8859-2". I want to encode this value in "UTF-8" in python.

I used following code in python(2.7) to convert it but the converted value ["**confrčres**"] is different from original value [**"confrères"**].

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import chardet
import codecs

a1=codecs.open('.../test.txt', 'r')

a=a1.read()

b = a.decode(chardet.detect(a)['encoding']).encode('utf8')

a1=codecs.open('.../test_out.txt', 'w').write(b)
```

Any idea how to get actual value but in UTF8 encoded format in the output file.

Thanks

Comment: Note that ISO-8859-2 *does not have any codepoint for `è`*. You cannot encode that character with that codec.

Answer (score 5):

If you *know* the codec used, don't use `chardet`. Character detection is never foolproof, the library guessed wrong for your file.

Note that ISO-8859-2 is the wrong codec, as that codec cannot even encode the letter `è`. You have ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) or Windows codepage 1252 data instead; `è` in 8859-1 and cp1252 is encoded to 0xE8, and 0xE8 in 8859-2 is `č`:

```
>>> print u'confrčres'.encode('iso-8859-2').decode('iso-8859-1')
confrères
```

Was 8859-2 perhaps the guess `chardet` made?

You can use the [`io` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) to handle decoding and encoding on the fly; it is the same codebase that handles all I/O in Python 3 and has fewer issues than `codecs`:

```
from shutil import copyfileobj

with open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1') as inf:
    with open('test_out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outf:
        copyfileobj(inf, outf)
```

I used [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to handle the copying across of data.

Comment: Thanks Martjin... It worked perfectly fine... I have around 300 files in a folder with different encoding methods - example : TIS-620, ascii, ISO-8859-1, EUC-JP -  can you help me in finding existing encoding method for each file and use it dynamically in the above code?

Comment: @annamalaimuthuraman: if you have *many* files, then `chardet` may be an option, just take into account that it'll get at least some of the guesses wrong.